# can't play wmv files - Failed to initialize the VAAPI device

Tags: vlc, ubuntu-restricted-extras, libav, wmv

I'm trying to run wmv files, and tryed some advices from here, but without any success. I have `vlc` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. I also did a `purge`, `autoremove` and re-`install`them.

This is what I get.

```
~/Downloads$ vlc test_wmv.wmv 
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x1260058] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
"sni-qt/11611" WARN  08:10:57.390 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE 
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[0x7f24d0c5da78] vaapi generic error: Failed to initialize the VAAPI device
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[0x7f24d0c6aeb8] vaapi generic error: Failed to initialize the VAAPI device
libva info: VA-API version 0.35.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[0x7f24c8000958] vaapi generic error: Failed to initialize the VAAPI device
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
[0x7f24c0001248] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
[0x7f24d80009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)
[0x7f24d80009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[wmv3 @ 0x7f24d0c58ee0] warning: first frame is no keyframe
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the [VLC wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding/) reveals the following:

> On modern Ubuntu distributions, first install the hardware support
>   (packages i965-va-driver, libva-intel-vaapi-driver and vainfo) and
>   then activate GPU hardware acceleration in Preferences ->
>   Input&Codecs.
>
> Install terminal command: sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
>   libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo
>
> The following video codecs are supported: MPEG-1, MPEG-2, MPEG-4
>   Visual, WMV3, VC-1 and H.264 (MPEG-4 AVC).